# PyGame flickering issue

Tags: python, pygame

I've made several small programs in PyGame and for my latest attempt I have added scrolling (push arrow keys) but when it happens the sprites flicker. I've tried to pinpoint the issue but cannot.

The drawing section happens in [engine.screen.py redraw() and update_window()](https://github.com/Teifion/sequtus/blob/master/engine/screen.py#L33)

[Github repository of code](https://github.com/Teifion/sequtus)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered swapping lines 48 and 49 in screen.py? :) Not sure, but maybe you ought to call display.flip() *after* rendering the sprites?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have vertical sync enabled? And set framerate to 60, for a nice look.